# java-- library/method that keeps track of bandwidth used and other parameters when a java app is being run

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am working to create a web crawler in Java. The crawler visits websites, accesses/stores data in database using JDBC and also stores files locally or on cloud storage.

As part of the crawling, I want to note the exact details of usage for the crawler--

Parameters like--

```
Number of sites visited (HTTP+HTTPS)
Number of bytes of data received over one run of the crawler
Number of bytes of data sent over one run of the crawler
Number of rows updated/inserted/deleted/selected via JDBC over that run of the crawler
Number of bytes of data stored+accessed in local machine (on which the crawler is running)
Number of bytes of data stored+accessed in cloud storage (like Amazon S3)
```

Is there any quick way to accomplish some or all of the above? Maybe some library that has to be plugged in to my java app? Will I have to individually note down all of the above parameters at every stage when the crawler performs some action (like visit a website, download data etc)?? I dont want the program to get bogged down simply because I want to measure and track the above parameters.

I am looking to use the crawler as both a desktop app and web app, so solutions for both are welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I have to individually note down all of the above parameters at every stage when the crawler performs some action (like visit a website, download data etc)?

Yes.

You're adding numbers to integer or long values in a global statistics class you'll have to create for your application.  Your program should not get bogged down performing addition.